# Mac OS X Notes moved to Exchange disappear

Tags: mac, notes.app

I moved the notes from Local notes to Exchange, and then my Notes crashed. When i reopen the Notes, i dont see them in Exchange and neither in local Notes I dont see these are present in Recently deleted either. I tried reading NotesV6.storedata.html as well, but didnt work. Please help.

Comment: I looked into Library/Containers/com.apple.Notes/Data/Library/CoreData/ExternalRecords/NotesV4 path and see the externalRecords file present. But they are of zero size.

Comment: I wasn't able to follow the terminal steps as my Mac couldn't find the file. But I exported the ZICNOTEDATA into a cvs file, though the ZDATA column just shows random characters?

Answer (score 2):

I was able recover all the files i lost. Lucky enough.
You can follow following steps to achieve it.
Following used:
1. [mac_apt](https://github.com/ydkhatri/mac_apt)
2. [DB browser for sqlite](https://sqlitebrowser.org/)

1. Using mac_apt, i connected to database command below on terminal 
   ./mac_apt_singleplugin.app/Contents/MacOS/mac_apt_singleplugin -i ~/Library/Group\ Containers/group.com.apple.notes/NoteStore.sqlite -o ~/Desktop/Note/mactool/ NOTES
2. This will create a Notes.csv in our output folder provided. It will have all the notes present.
3. Open the CSV, You will see your note text in the column 'Data'. For me, the 'Data' didn't had complete text present, but was partial. To get entire note file i filtered on the 'Folder' (as i lost one specific folder data) and got 'ID' column.
4. I connected to NoteStore.sqlite database using DB browser for sqlite
5. Open the NoteStore.sqlite in SQLite Browser and
   run query as
   SELECT * from ZICNOTEDATA  where ZNOTE='ID';
   Click on each ZDATA entry and on the right side click 'Export'
6. Save the blob as whatever_filename.gz
7. Unzip the file using your preferred tool (i have used gunzip on Mac OS X)
8. You will get your plaintext at the beginning of the file ( there is more than just plain text ).

Comment: Hi @Xephonia, i downloaded `mac_apt` apps from https://github.com/ydkhatri/mac_apt/releases/tag/v0.4.1-beta but wasn't able to do what you did in 1. because of `permission denied` (Big Sur and Catalina). I already enabled the app to be opened in security settings. But no luck.. Any idea?